# Copy sheets from multiple excel files and paste into a new xlsx

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a folder that contains multiple Excel workbook each have a tab named the same thing. I would like to copy the tab from each workbook and put them into a new xlsx using powershell. 
Starting with: 20 Workbooks that have "sheet1" 
Desired result: 1 workbook that contain 20 "sheet1" tabs. 
Here is the code I started but I am not sure if I am on the right track here. I am new to powershell regardless of my user name. With the code below I am able to copy a worksheet from an xlsx and past it into a new xlsx. How can I copy the liked named sheet from multiple xlsx and put them into a new xlsx

```
Copy-ExcelWorksheet -SourceWorkbook ('c:\users\user1\test.xlsx') -SourceWorksheet 'Sheet1' -DestinationWorksheet Sheet1 -DestinationWorkbook 'c:\users\user1\test2.xlsx'
```

Comment: I find the ImportExcel module -very- helpful. `Find-Module -Name ImportExcel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ExcelObject=New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$ExcelObject.visible=$false
$ExcelFiles=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\user1

$Workbook=$ExcelObject.Workbooks.add()
$Worksheet=$Workbook.Sheets.Item('Sheet1')

foreach($ExcelFile in $ExcelFiles){

$Everyexcel=$ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFile.FullName)
$Everysheet=$Everyexcel.sheets.item('Sheet1')
$Everysheet.Copy($Worksheet)
$Everyexcel.Close()

}
$Workbook.Saveas("C:\Users\user1\test.xlsx")
$ExcelObject.Quit()
```